# Unexpected migration from Stack Overflow to the Code Review SE

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question, migrated-questions, user-experience

I recently just had one of my questions migrated https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10878/code-first-example-of-soa-with-rest without my consent and I don’t believe it belongs there. That site is to review code and I am not asking for my code to be reviewed I am asking a programming question related to "how" to rewrite it in such a way that it becomes SOA. A code first approach.

I kind of felt it was really rude, I was asked a question by someone if "I had heard of that site" then suddenly migrated and then he deleted his comment. Sorry to be abit alarmed and slightly outraged, but it’s not very welcoming and I still believe it doesn’t belong there. I mean its not even in league with the questions asked there.

Comment: Your consent is not needed for migration.

Comment: Like seriously "WTF" lol

Comment: I don’t mean it as a derogatory term, just my sheer displeasement to the callous nature on how it was shunted from SO, from the myriad of “Non” programming related questions on SO to my very much programming related question which would serve to help countless people searching the site for SOA including myself.

Comment: You seem to take the position that you have been harmed in some way or another. Keep in mind though that the most likely motivation of those involved is to give your question a good/better chance at a place they thought more appropriate/constructive for your question.

Comment: Also, fair warning since you're new to Meta: Downvotes here [mean something different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) than they do on the main site.

Comment: @Bart I probably have been harmed, 1) in not getting the question answered. 2) Not gaining the rep for my SO account (unsure). 3) The shock factor. I thought for me it would enlighten me to how SOA is done from a code first approach and may have become a popular question as only scrubs/noobs like me really search key phrases like how to implement SOA or SOA with REST. I just felt abit cheated even with good intentions in mind.

Comment: `1) in not getting the question answered` You do not have the right to have your question answered. You have the right to ask questions, but that doesn't mean you're entitled to answers. `2) Not gaining the rep for my SO account (unsure).` You do not have the right to reputation. What reputation you get and where it goes is for the community to decide. `3) The shock factor.` The shock of having a question moved to a theoretically more appropriate place? There are many Stack Exchange site; having your question moved is not something that should be shocking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L.B. indeed left [the comment you describe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149048/code-first-example-of-soa-with-rest?noredirect=1#comment13015241_10149048):

> Do you know [this site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? – L.B 33 mins ago

He probably also flagged the question for moderator attention and asked that it be migrated to the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site, where he felt it would be a better fit.

Subsequently, a moderator processed the flag, agreed with the suggestion, and cast a binding vote, which caused the question to be immediately migrated to the new site.

L.B. didn't delete his comment—in fact, it's still visible on [the question stub that remains on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149048/code-first-example-of-soa-with-rest?noredirect=1). Rather, his comment was automatically removed when the question was migrated to Code Review because it's just obsolete noise there.

The consent of the asker is not required for a question to be migrated to another site. The intent is to get the question to place where it is A) more appropriate and B) more likely to get high-quality answers.

If you fundamentally disagree with the migration, you can flag your question on the new site and ask one of the moderators there to reject the migration.

But just for reference, the rule of thumb is that questions with *already working code* that are merely seeking suggestions on how to improve it are best asked on Code Review.

I'm sorry you found the migration experience to be an unpleasant one. We've tried to make it as user friendly as possible. For example, you are automatically redirected to your question's new home whenever you try to access it; that way, you don't have to hunt around for it or change your bookmarks. If you have specific suggestions on how else it can be improved, please share them.

Comment: Ah well thank your for answering that, explains alot. It sounds almost batch automated, well I am going to feel silly asking for it to be migrated back so I guess I will leave it there and hope that after they answer the "Big Questions" on that site they may have time for mine :).

Comment: I do however reserve the right to say that I am not seeking suggestions on how to improve my code. I am asking "how" to code a specific way. I look for no improvements.

Comment: So you're not actually saying that, @Kirsty - you're just reserving the right to say it?  I kid, I kid.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Just don't let Petrotta catch you having fun.

Comment: Erm, what, @jonsca? Do I have a doppelganger?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I always wanted to say that to someone when they had made a funny (as a reference to the "crap" you gave me in my 'u and i' question so long ago), but it works doubly well here

Comment: @jonsca: Oh, right. Well, if it makes you feel better, bad grammar and spelling bothers me so much that I scrawled over some documentation my co-worker had tacked on his wall yesterday. Corrected "effect" to "affect". Felt much better.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Next stop for you is the basement.  They're going to take away your Swingline.  Feel free to adopt the "Just don't let Petrotta catch you ____________" meme for your office.  I won't sue.